# Interaction with green chapter titles -- right paren shows up black

Tags: chapters, context, interaction

I use `\setupinteraction[state=start]` and `\setupcolors[state=start]` for making the entries of the table of contents interactive, and all entries show up green. But in the backmatter a chapter title containing the character `)` (right paren), only this character shows up uncoloured (black).

Is this a bug?

MWE:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\definecombinedlist[content][chapter]
\setupcombinedlist[content][level=4, alternative=c]
\setbreakpoints[compound]
\starttext
\completecontent
\chapter{Noten bij de digitale (her)uitgave}
\chapter{Noten bij de digitale (her)\-uitgave}
\chapter{Tries: her)uit}
\chapter{Tries: her)ui}
\chapter{Tries: er)uit}
\stoptext
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: A small compilable example to reproduce the problem would be welcome.

Comment: I'll try to produce a MWE.

Comment: Costs some time to produce a MEW (having a long environment file), but interestingly I found that commenting out `\setbreakpoints[compound]` eliminates the problem...

Comment: And it seems to matter what character occurs directly after the right paren `)`

Comment: It would help if your MWE included the document class and packages used.

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is not Latex but Context and the code is complete. Anyway, this is only a small bug, the current beta does not produce it. Workaround is to place `\-` after the right paren.

Comment: I voted to close as the problem was a (now resolved) bug.